# How I can add Custom Component to the omniBox region in Salesforce Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I created Custom Component that implements 'forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes' interface, but I can't add it to the omniBox section.
What I should do to accomplish this?